# unlock AFI value NFCV

Tags: android, nfc, unlock, iso-15693

I have problem how to unlock AFI value on NFCV tag. I changed AFI value with 0x27 followed by a lock AFI 0x28. Is there some way how I can unlock it? Also how can I detect if AFI value is locked or unlocked? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no unlock command at all. If 0x27 fails it's locked, the lock makes a tag write-once. That's the way it is.